# Javascript - multidimensional set value not working

Tags: javascript

```
var myArray = [];

myArray[0].binary = 'qweqwe';
myArray[0].src    = 'qweqwe';

myArray[1].binary = 'zxczxc';
myArray[1].src    = 'zxczxc';

myArray[2].binary = 'asdasd';
myArray[2].src    = 'asdasd';

console.log(myArray);
```

please help me... this is not working why? any other solution? cause I need it badly... need it fast please..

Comment: why downvote? I need help please make comment not downvote for nothing...

Comment: Before set property to Object you should create empty object like so myArray[0] = {};  myArray[1] = {};  myArray[2] = {};

Answer (score 0):

`myArray[0].binary = 'qweqwe';`?  You are setting property `binary` of undefined.

*So instead **Try** something like this*:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = {}
myArray[0]["binary"] = 'qweqwe';
myArray[0]["src"]    = 'qweqwe';

myArray[1] = {}
myArray[1]["binary"] = 'zxczxc';
myArray[1]["src"]    = 'zxczxc';

myArray[2] = {}
myArray[2]["binary"] = 'asdasd';
myArray[2]["src"]    = 'asdasd';
```

Comment: Why not use an object initializer? Why use property names in quotes?

Comment: I just posted this guessing he is looking for this, his code is similar to this. But accept ur comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you access an array entry that doesn't exist, you get the value `undefined`. Your code is trying to add properties to `undefined`, which you can't do (you get a `TypeError`).

To add objects to your array, you add *objects*, perhaps using an object initializer:

```
var myArray = [];

myArray[0] = {
    binary: 'qweqwe',
    src: 'qweqwe'
};

myArray[1] = {
    binary: 'zxczxc',
    src: 'zxczxc'
};

myArray[2] = {
    binary: 'asdasd',
    src: 'asdasd'
};

console.log(myArray);
```

You can actually combine those with the array initializer:

```
var myArray = [
    {
        binary: 'qweqwe',
        src: 'qweqwe'
    },
    {
        binary: 'zxczxc',
        src: 'zxczxc'
    },
    {
        binary: 'asdasd',
        src: 'asdasd'
    }
];

console.log(myArray);
```

...which may be clearer, and has the advantage of making it a bit easier to reorder them (e.g., in the source, if you need to put them in a different initial order). Or you can use `push` to make it easier to reorder them:

```
var myArray = [];

myArray.push({
    binary: 'qweqwe',
    src: 'qweqwe'
});

myArray.push({
    binary: 'zxczxc',
    src: 'zxczxc'
});

myArray.push({
    binary: 'asdasd',
    src: 'asdasd'
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Any of those works, pick the one most appropriate to what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply like this:

```
// SET all at once
var myArray = [
 {binary:"qweqwe", src:"qweqwe"},
 {binary:"zxczxc", src:"zxczxc"},
 {binary:"asdasd", src:"asdasd"}
];

// ADD new key
myArray[3] = {binary:"ioioio", src:"ioioio"};

alert(console.log(myArray);
```

PS: "downvoting" is because you did not really try to solve the prob. before posting your question. array and object in Js are a basic topics and can be find everywhere on the web ;)